# Elasticsearch: Disable indexing but apply copy_to for a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use a field for only copying purpose and not to index itself with below mapping

```
        "Line2": {
            "type":     "text",
            "copy_to": "AllFields" ,
            "enabled": false
        }
```

But getting exception

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping
>   definition for [Line2] has unsupported parameters:  [enabled :
>   false]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse
>   mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [Line2] has unsupported
>   parameters:  [enabled :
>   false]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping
>   definition for [Line2] has unsupported parameters:  [enabled :
>   false]"}},"status":400}

Can this be done ?

**ES version : 6.7**

Comment: Change the type from "text" to "object" and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to index (make searchable) a field use `"index": false` for the field.

```
"Line2": {
    "type": "text",
    "copy_to": "AllFields",
    "index": false
  }
```